# Shared observable and startWith operator

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a question regarding multicasted observables and an unexpected (for me) behaviour I noticed.

```
const a = Observable.fromEvent(someDom, 'click')
  .map(e => 1)
  .startWith(-1)
  .share();

const b = a.pairwise();

a.subscribe(a => {
  console.log(`Sub 1: ${a}`);
});

a.subscribe(a => {
  console.log(`Sub 2: ${a}`)
});

b.subscribe(([prevA, curA]) => {
  console.log(`Pairwise Sub: (${prevA}, ${curA})`);
});
```

So, there is a shared observable a, which emits 1 on every click event. -1 is emitted due to the startWith operator.
The observable b just creates a new observable by pairing up latest two values from a.

My expectation was:

```
[-1, 1] // first click
[ 1, 1] // all other clicks
```

What I observed was:

```
[1, 1] // from second click on, and all other clicks
```

What I noticed is that the value -1 is emitted immediately and consumed by Sub 1, before even Sub 2 is subscribed to the observable and since a is multicasted, Sub 2 is too late for the party.

Now, I know that I could multicast via BehaviourSubject and not use the startWith operator, but I want to understand the use case of this scenario when I use startWith and multicast via share.

As far as I understand, whenever I use .share() and .startWith(x), only one subscriber will be notified about the startWith value, since all other subscribers are subscribed after emitting the value.

So is this a reason to multicast via some special subject (Behavior/Replay...) or am I missing something about this startWith/share scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Can you please provide an example with the BehaviourSubject?

Answer (score 11):

This is actually correct behavior.

The `.startWith()` emits its value to every new subscriber, not only the first one. The reason why `b.subscribe(([prevA, curA])` never receives it is because you're using multicasting with `.share()` (aka `.publish().refCount()`).

This means that the first `a.subscribe(...)` makes the `.refCount()` to subscribe to its source and it'll stay subscribed (note that Observable `.fromEvent(someDom, 'click')` never completes).

Then when you finally call `b.subscribe(...)` it'll subscribe only to the `Subject` inside `.share()` and will never go through `.startWith(-1)` because it's multicasted and already subscribed in `.share()`.

Comment: Hey! That was also what I understood, thanks a lot for elaborating more on why the observation makes sense. One solution to this scenario is also to use connectable observables and call connect after setting up the subscriptions. This way all subscribers will get the startWith value.